# mongoengine: datetime object getting converted to string once saved using insert_one

Tags: mongodb, datetime, mongoengine, isodate

I am trying to create a session_expiry time using Python and then inserting the session_expiry in mongo db using insert_one() method.

once the data in inserted in mongodb, while querying the mongo shell I am getting date in string format.

This is how it is getting stored -

```
"session_expiry" : "2023-06-23T19:55:41.551199"
```

but I want it to get stored in ISO format something like below date -

```
"session_expiry" : ISODate("2023-06-23T13:44:53.740Z")
```

```
import datetime
session_expiry = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=90)
```

type of session_expiry is datetime.datetime`

```
`In [2]: session_expiry = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=90)

In [3]: session_expiry
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 23, 21, 55, 49, 2328)

In [4]: type(session_expiry)
Out[4]: datetime.datetime`
```

Answer (score 0):

python:

```
import datetime
import pymongo

db = pymongo.MongoClient()['test']
session_expiry = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=90)
db['mycollection'].insert_one({'session_expiry': session_expiry})
```

mongosh:

```
test> db.mycollection.findOne()
{
  _id: ObjectId("64962241fa935efe824f5d07"),
  session_expiry: ISODate("2023-06-24T00:22:49.372Z")
}
```

Comment: sorry, my bad, I am using mongoengine instead of pymongo.

The way you suggested above, I am doing exactly the same.

It seems it is getting changed to string at the time of insertion.

Answer (score 0):

To store datetime in mongoengine. You use `DateTimeField`

Example:

```
from mongoengine import *
import datetime

class Token(Document):
   session_expiry = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=90))
```